# Can't get upload ticket from vimeo api after move of application

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I've created a page that connects to the Vimeo API using an APP I created.

This APP worked fine on my own host but now I've moved it to the clients server I can't get past the first hurdle - getting the error:

Unable to get an upload ticket

I've tried using the token that worked previously on my own server to no avail and created a new token with all the scopes set but this doesnt work either.

I thought it was a SSL issue (as they suggest on one of the forum questions: http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/ but making the SSL Curl change or trying to use the certificate makes very little difference).

The API looks great I just wish it gave more useful error messages!

Does anyone have any ideas as I've asked Vimeo on their support and didn't get anything back from them (after a week) and their forum is almost closed as it's so quiet!

Many Thanks,

Comment: Unable to get upload ticket is an error message thrown by the php library here: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php/blob/master/src/Vimeo/Vimeo.php#L350. Can you post the contents of the $ticket variable?

Comment: Hi the ticket comes back with: 

array(3) {
  ["body"]=>
  NULL
  ["status"]=>
  int(0)
  ["headers"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
} is pretty useless really - I've checked the tokens etc and its all correct.

Comment: Status 0 means it never reached vimeo. Try adding a curl_error (http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) call here https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php/blob/master/src/Vimeo/Vimeo.php#L441 and see what it says

Comment: This is it - I should have realised this sooner - perhaps the API can manage this? Many thanks for the insight - I've managed to get it working from this error.

Comment: Yeah the library should add that. It's on our list!